# Refused entry with correct visa and documents

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, denial-of-entry

I got a Schengen visa from the Polish Embassy in Cairo in February 2017, and I traveled to Warsaw. At the Warsaw airport, they asked me about my return ticket and hotel reservation; I had already given them all the documents. But, for unknown reasons, I was refused to entry into Poland and was sent to the transit area and my visa was stamped as revoked.
-reason (E) not hold enough documents justifies purpose of stay , 
 I hold return ticket and hotel reservation and medical insurance, but for them not enough.

Can I  apply again for another visa? Does this mean I have a ban?

Comment: Did they tell you that you have a ban?  Also, they're required to give you both a sheet of paper with a reason for the refusal of entry and one with a reason for the revocation of the visa, so I'm skeptical about your assertion that this was done "for unknown reason."

Comment: the reason is (E) not hold enough documents justifies purpose of visiting the country...I show them enough money to stay and booking reservation

Comment: It sounds like a case of incoherent premise. What was your purpose in visiting Poland? Please update your question so that it provides complete information. We cannot spend the whole time pulling information from you. Close voting as unclear.

Comment: And please clarify: when you arrived in Warsaw, did you have with you all the documents you included in your visa application; did you have a return ticket?

Comment: Money to stay and booking reservation has nothing to do with the *purpose* of your trip; they only concern your ability to support yourself.  The purpose of your trip is the reason you want to go to Poland.  For example, if you said that you were going to attend a conference, but you had no evidence of any actual connection to the conference, then you have not justified the purpose of your visit.  The same would be true if you say you are visiting a friend but cannot show any evidence that you actually know someone in Poland.

Comment: @phoog nice one. Get the OP to add his premise and the info surrounding it. I bet it will be an incoherent premise given what the OP has provided so far.

Comment: Why were you going to Poland?

Comment: *"I had already given them all the documents"* Do you mean you had provided these documemts with the visa application or that you provided these documents to the border guard who challenged you?